# Writing username and password to a CSV file after reading it from another CSV file using java in Selenium

Tags: java, csv, selenium

I have written the code for reading the contents (Username and password) from a CSV file. Now, I need to write these contents to another CSV file. Please help me with a good suggestion.

```
public class NewCsvClass {
    // private static final String FILE_HEADER = "Username,Password,Result";
    // private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
    public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception {

        // csv reader aswathy -start
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("/home/user/Documents/UrmilaDocs/CSV PAck/testCSV.csv"));
        String[] nextLine;

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
        driver.get(appUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

            String user_name = nextLine[0];
            String pass_word = nextLine[1];

            System.out.println("Username: " + user_name);
            System.out.println("Password: " + pass_word);

            // //stackoverflow
            // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            // String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
            // driver.get(appUrl);
            // driver.manage().window().maximize();

            WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']"));
            username.clear();
            username.sendKeys(user_name);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            // try
            try {
                WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']"));
                password.clear();
                password.sendKeys(pass_word);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signIn']")).click();
                Thread.sleep(8000);

                // click on 'Google Apps' icon
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbwa']/div[1]/a")).click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);

                // Click on 'Gmail' icon to navigate to inbox page
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb23']/span[1]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("Login Success");

                // Click on user name first letter circle icon
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);

                // click on 'Signout' button
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb_71']")).click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("Logout Success");

                /*
                 * click on 'Signin with a different account ' option (since, after signing out from // the first user,
                 * the page is navigated to password entry page, which is supposed to navigate to // username/mailid
                 * entry page
                 */

                try {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account-chooser-link']")).click();
                    // driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='link-signin-different']/a")).click();
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                // /* In 'Choose an Account page', Click on 'Add Account' button */
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account-chooser-add-account']")).click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                //
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Login failed!");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='link-signin-different']/a")).click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account-chooser-add-account']")).click();
                Thread.sleep(10000);

            } // catch closed
            // //closing driver & firefox
            // driver.close();
            // System.exit(0);
            // end
        } // while end

        // //closing driver & firefox
        // driver.close();
        // //csv reader aswathy -end
        System.exit(0); // closing firefox

        // Writing the CSV file to another CSV file
        String csv = "/home/user/Documents/UrmilaDocs/CSV PAck/testCSV.csv";
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));
        String[] username = "testuser01.zyx#testuser07#testuser2#testuser01.zyx#tester2.zyx#testernew779".split("#");
        String[] password = "testuser0123#user0123#user0123#user0123#user0123#user0123".split("#");
        writer.writeNext(username);
        writer.writeNext(password);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please attach your first attempts of writing this codes, or where are you blocked.

Comment: @Johnny Kutnowski: please have a look at my edited question. At the bottom of the code I have specified the CSV write.

Comment: Did you get this working? Was my answer close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see the import statements but are you using com.csvreader.CsvWriter, that is the JavaCSV API?

If so, try inserting

```
writer.endRecord();
```

before

```
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Data plays very important role for executing testcases, using which we can perform data quality testing with different test data.
To perform these we need Excel or csv to store data.

OpenCSV is a library which used to read and write data to an excel.

Below is the code for writing data to an excel:

File file = new File(filePath);

```
try { 
  
    // create FileWriter object with file as parameter 
    FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(file); 

    // create CSVWriter object filewriter object as parameter 
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile); 

    // Add header to csv 
    String[] header = { "StudentName", "Class", "ID" }; 
    writer.writeNext(header); 

    // Add data to csv 
    String[] data1 = { "Arman", "10", "1" }; 
    writer.writeNext(data1); 
    String[] data2 = { "Sanjay", "10", "2" }; 
    writer.writeNext(data2); 

    // closing writer connection 
    writer.close(); 
}
```